# I'm trying to figure out how to get the div *topnav* background colour to fit the page width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to get the div `topnav` background color to fit the page width from side to side with no gaps. I hope you understand what I mean. if you need any more info just let me know.
Page showing gap:
[image: page showing gap]

**HTML and CSS code**:

```css
body {background-color: burlywood;}
  #heading1{position: relative; text-align: center; top: 50px;}
  #topnav{background-color: chocolate;
  font-size: 30px; 
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  word-spacing: 70px;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="heading1">Hello World</h1>
    <div id="topnav">
      <nav>
        <a href="#"> About</a>
        <a href="#"> sales</a>
        <a href="#"> cart</a>
        <a href="#"> home</a>
      </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your html is not valid ( orphan closing ul ); topnav with height 100%? your gap is probably the padding of the body itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put  `body { padding:0; margin:0; }` in style

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mantain automatic margin and padding of body you can add this to #topnav

```
width: 100vw;
margin-left: -8px;
```

You also set to 0 margin and padding of body:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title></title>
    <style>
    body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    #heading1{position: relative; text-align: center; top: 50px;}
#topnav{background-color: chocolate;
font-size: 30px; 
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
word-spacing: 70px;
width: 100%; height: 100%;
bottom: 80px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="heading1">Hello World</h1>

<div id="topnav">

    <nav>


    <a href="#"> About</a>
    <a href="#"> sales</a>
    <a href="#"> cart</a>
    <a href="#"> home</a>
</ul>

</nav>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is of not removing default margin of body which is causing space in left and right direction.

```css
 body { padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#heading1 {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50px;
}

#topnav {
    background-color: chocolate;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    word-spacing: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 80px;
}
#topnav ul { margin: 0;}
#topnav li { display: inline-block; list-style-type: none;}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading1">Hello World</h1>

<div id="topnav">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> About</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#"> sales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> cart</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

There is also some syntax problem in the HTML part. Check the above solution which includes both removing of default space and HTML correction with styling.